# Incorporating feedback to retrain WordToVec for finding document similarity

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gensim, cosine-similarity

I have trained Gensim's WordToVec on a text corpus,converted it to DocToVec and then used cosine similarity to find the similarity between documents. I need to suggest similar documents. Now suppose among the top 5 suggestions for a particular document, we manually find that 3 of them are not similar.Can this feedback be incorporated in retraining the model?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you mean by "converted [a Word2Vec model] to DocToVec". The gensim `Doc2Vec` class doesn't use or require a `Word2Vec` model as input.

But, if you have many sets of hand-curated "this is a good suggestion" or "this is a bad suggestion" pairs for your corpus, you can use the model's scoring against all those to compare models, and train many variant models (with different model parameter values like `size`, `window`, `min_count`, `sample`, etc), picking the one that scores best on your tests.

That sort of automated-parameter-search is the most straightforward way to use performance on real evaluation data to adjust an unsupervised model like `Word2Vec`.

(Depending on the specifics of your data and problem-domain, you might also start to notice patterns in where the model is better or worse, that help you hand-tune parts of the data preprocessing. For example, a different handling of capitalization or tokenization might be suggested by error cases.)